# Refresh on ListView.builder while click on row view of item builder Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

I am working on the flutter application where I am using `ListView.builder` class inside the BottomSheet popup. I need to develop something where user can select multiple data from the ListView.

For this I have used `Map mapProfCredsT = new Map<dynamic, bool>();` for storing click events of each cell inside the listview.
Also, I have used  `setState() {}` on each click events so that my data should be updated. But even after this I can't able to update the UI for my each cell after the click event.

Please consider the following code snippet:

```
Map mapProfCredsT = new Map<dynamic, bool>();
```

on response of API call I am adding all flags with each ID as false,

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrProfCredsCount; i++) {
int id_key = respProfCreds['payload']['user_type'][i]['id'];
mapProfCredsT[id_key] = false; }
```

Now the color of the container and Icon is dependent on the click event of the container which is as below:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Material(
  type: MaterialType.transparency,
  child: Scaffold(
    key: scaffoldState,
    body: SafeArea(
      child: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        color: Colors.teal,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Text(
                'BottomSheet Sample',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 30.0,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        if (isChanged) {
                          isChanged = false;
                        } else {
                          isChanged = true;
                        }
                      });
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                      child: Text('Change'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      // scaffoldState.currentState.showBottomSheet(
                      // scaffoldState.currentState.showBottomSheet(
                      showModalBottomSheet(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (builder) {
                            return new Container(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              height: 70.0.h,
                              child: Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Container(
                                    height: 10.0.w,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    child: Center(
                                      child: Text(
                                        'Professional Creds',
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: Container(
                                      child: ListView.builder(
                                          itemCount: arrProfCredsCount,
                                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                            return ConstrainedBox(
                                              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                                minHeight: 15.0.w,
                                              ),
                                              child: GestureDetector(
                                                onTap: () {
                                                  var profID = respProfCreds['payload']['user_type'][index]['id'];
                                                  print('Position on bottomsheet : $profID');
                                                  setState(() {
                                                    // Update text data..
                                                    respProfCreds['payload']['user_type'][index]['title'] =
                                                        'Test ${respProfCreds['payload']['user_type'][index]['id']}';
                                                  });
                                                },
                                                child: Container(
                                                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(2.0.w),
                                                  // color: Colors.tealAccent,
                                                  // color: mapProfCredsT[respProfCreds['payload']['user_type'][index]['id']]? themeYellow: Colors.blueGrey,
                                                  color: isChanged ? themeYellow : Colors.blueGrey,
                                                  child: Center(
                                                    child: Text(
                                                      '${respProfCreds['payload']['user_type'][index]['title']}',
                                                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                                      style: kDataSingleSelectionBottomNav,
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            );
                                          }),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            );
                          });
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                      child: Text('Open'),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);}
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here that doesn't allow me to update my records.

Comment: Post your full code, specially the parent of ```GestureDetector```

Comment: @ikerfah I have updated my parent of GestureDetector, Can you please help me, what is wrong or missing here.

Comment: what's the use of mapProfCredsT[profId] ?

Comment: @TipuSultan This is the map I have used for storing my click events which is like: Map mapProfCredsT = new Map<dynamic, bool>();  Also mapProfCredsT[profId] used for updating my value for the specific key which used as profId.

Comment: yes, but in your code you declead isSelected. and want to update the ui based on isSelected. but you didn't use isSelected. where you used that variable?

Comment: @TipuSultan okay I have removed isSelected to mapProfCreds[profId] but still, perform the same. Is there something else that I can do here to force refresh my ListView?

Comment: post all your ```build```

Comment: @ikerfah I have updated my whole build file on the code now. Also, I have tested a few scenarios when I am using the ListView builder independently in the screen then this will work perfectly, but when I use this ListView.builder inside the showModalBottomSheet then these whole issues are started.

Comment: Wrap your ```Container```  (child of ```showModalBottomSheet```) with ```StatefulBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context,void Function(void Function()) setState) {return Container(..);)}```, be sure that you are using ```setState``` from the ```StatefulBuilder``` (You can use different name to avoid confusion) , check and tell me

Comment: @ikerfah Yupp.. This working perfectly... :-)  Thank you :-)

Comment: I will share as answer with some details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the `showModalBottomSheet`is not part of your `StatefulWidget`, Which means calling `setState` with refresh your `StatefulWidget` only and not the `BottomSheet` since it is not part of it.

So in order to fix this. You do that by

- Passing a `StatefulWidget` to your `showModalBottomSheet` builder
- Use `StatefulBuilder` as a child to your `showModalBottomSheet` builder and then use `setState` from this `StatefulBuilder` , Use different name to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

bottomSheet will never be updated by setState for that you need to use stateful builder.
And inside this sheet wherever you wanna use setState use updateState as declared in statefulBuilder.

```
    showModalBottomSheet(
          context: context,
          builder: (builder) {
            return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context,updateState){
//stateful builder added over here
              return Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                height: 70.0.h,
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 10.0.w,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'Professional Creds',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: arrProfCredsCount,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return ConstrainedBox(
                                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                  minHeight: 15.0.w,
                                ),
                                child: GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    var profID = respProfCreds['payload']['user_type'][index]['id'];
                                    print('Position on bottomsheet : $profID');
                                    updateState(() {
                                      // Update text data..
                                      respProfCreds['payload']['user_type'][index]['title'] =
                                      'Test ${respProfCreds['payload']['user_type'][index]['id']}';
                                    });
                                  },
                                  child: Container(
                                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(2.0.w),
                                    // color: Colors.tealAccent,
                                    // color: mapProfCredsT[respProfCreds['payload']['user_type'][index]['id']]? themeYellow: Colors.blueGrey,
                                    color: isChanged ? themeYellow : Colors.blueGrey,
                                    child: Center(
                                      child: Text(
                                        '${respProfCreds['payload']['user_type'][index]['title']}',
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                        style: kDataSingleSelectionBottomNav,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            }),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            });
          });
```